# Xamarin.Forms ObservableCollection with WordPress API json

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, wordpress-rest-api

I am having many issues with deserializing wordpress api json into an observable collection. Does anyone have any experience with this at all?

Here's the issue I am having:

I am able to deserialize json into a Jcontainer, but when I specifically try to deserialize it into an ObservableCollection I am not able to do so. It tells me it can not convert the json object into an ObservableCollection. It's driving me nuts!

Can anyone provide me with an actual working example of being able to deserialize wordpress API json into an ObservableCollection and display it in a ListView. I think it's possible I just do not understand how this is supposed to work.

Btw, I have been able to make other API calls, deserialize them, and bind them to ui elements.

EDIT:

Here's what I have right now.

Notification Page

```
    public partial class Notification : ContentPage
{
    public Notification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NotificationList.ItemsSource = NotificationData();
    }
    public static async Task<Alerts> NotificationData()
    {
        var notification = await GetAlerts.GetAlert();
        return (Alerts)notification;
    }
}
```

Get Notifications

```
    public class GetAlerts
    {
    public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Alerts>> GetAlert()
    {
        string WPPosts = "URL";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(WPPosts).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Alerts data = null;
        if (response != null)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string content_sanitized = RemoveTags(content);
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alerts>(content_sanitized);
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static string RemoveTags(string content)
    {
        string returnStr = "";
        bool insideTag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; ++i)
        {
            char c = content[i];
            if (c == '<')
                insideTag = true;
            if (!insideTag)
                returnStr += c;
            if (c == '>')
                insideTag = false;
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
}
```

Here is the main error I am receiving, among a few

```
Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Namespace.Alerts>' to `System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)
```

I won't list the class that I am deserializing to here.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you're doing first, instead of asking us to come up with a solution from scratch?

Comment: Added edits. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: Which specific line is throwing the error?  The first obvious error I see is that you are trying to cast an ObservableCollection<Alerts> to Alerts, which won't work.  Is the Alerts class a single object, or a collection of objects?

Comment: Alerts is a collection of objects that inherits from ObservableCollection. The specific error I'm getting is when I try to assign NotificationData() to ItemSource in the code behind file.

Comment: if Alerts is already an OC, why does GetAlert() return an OC<Alerts>?  You really need to think through the chain of types that are being returned by GetAlert() and NotificationData() and assigned to your ItemSource.

Comment: That is an interesting observation and a good question. I guess what my example is doing is GetAlert is returning type OC<Alerts> and NotificationData is returning type Alerts which would cause problems when  it is bound to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you deserialize your data into a list.

```
var list = JsonConvert.Deserialize<IList<MyObject>>(jsonString);
```

Then create an ObservableCollection from that.

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection(list);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adam for trying to answer this question. I am still having trouble so I am going to give your method a try!